# Excel: Alt + Enter for multiple cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, text-editors, text-editing, text-formatting

I would like to change the first table into a wrap texted version of numbers & (xxx),  making two lines in each cell. What is the best option for this, as I have >100 cells so it's not feasible to do so manually via `Alt`+`Enter`

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Can you not just highlight the column and set it to "Wrap Text" and then just adjust the width?

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following steps.

1. Using formula "`=SUBSTITUTE(RC[-3],"(",CHAR(10)&"(")`" to add Line Break before the the left bracket. Then pull down and pull right to apply the formula to all cells with data.
2. Right click these cells > Format Cells  > Check the box of "Wrap text".

[image]